# Ionic SqlStorage vs Storage

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, local-storage

Most of the examples I see use `Storage` and `SqlStorage`:

```
import {Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
storage.set(...);
storage.get(...).then(...);
```

But the code I'm working on uses `SqlStorage` directly:

```
import {SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

let storage = new SqlStorage();
storage.set(...);
storage.get(...).then(...);
```

**What's the difference? What's the reason to use `Storage`?**

---

I notice that use of `LocalStorage` is the same (minus the `query` method). That is, you can use `let storage = new Storage(LocalStorage)` and then use the same code to set and get values as before. So it makes some sense to me that perhaps some people will want this sort of code:

```
import {Storage, SqlStorage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyService {
    public storage:Storage;

    constructor(local) {
        if (local) {
            this.storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);
        }
        else {
            this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
        }
    }
```

Does that make sense? Is that the only reason? Could you do the following, without the Storage class?

```
import {Storage, SqlStorage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

local = ...

var storage:Storage;
if (local) storage = new LocalStorage();
else storage = new SqlStorage();
```

Part of my confusion stems from not finding documentation. A link or two would be greatly appreciated.